# prove that sum of quadric form less than the frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, clustering

I was reading this famous paper ([Clustering Large Graphs via the Singular Value DecompositionClustering Large Graphs via the Singular Value Decomposition](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/kannan/Papers/5authorsjournal.pdf)) and find difficulty in understanding a step of the proof here.

[image: page 15]

I do not know why the quadratic term is equal to the `(t, t)` entry of `AA^T - CC^T` and thus the inequality holds. Could someone give a walk through or calculation about this?

Comment: this seems to be Bessel's Inequality adapated to matrices.  Re-writing it as $\sum_{t=1}^k \Big(\text{trace}\big( Z\mathbf h_t \mathbf h_t^T\big)\Big)^2$ with $Z:= (AA^T - CC^T)$ should make this clear.  Note: posting images instead of writing up the relevant section in LaTeX is widely deprecated on this site -- e.g. images are not tractable to those with screen readers.

Comment: Thank you! You are so clever. How did you thought about this?

Comment: It was the first thing that came to mind actually.  That's the way pattern recognition works I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the full answer. All scalars are in $\mathbb R$ and all matrices are $\text{m x m}$.

We have orthogonal matrix
$H := \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\mathbf h_1 & \mathbf h_2 & \cdots & \mathbf h_m
\end{array}\bigg] $
this means $\mathbf h_r^T \mathbf h_j =1$ *iff* $r=j$ and $0$ otherwise

(note this is a square matrix $H$ which differs slightly from that in the original post -- the OP considers a truncated $H$ that only has $k$ columns.  But square, and indeed orthogonal, matrices are more pleasant to work with so I use the full square $H$.)

$Z$ is *any* real symmetric matrix.  At the end of either proof we may select $Z:= (AA^T - CC^T)$, to get the desired result.

**first proof**
This is a short and simple argument.  For any square matrix we have
$\sigma_\max^2 \geq \big\vert\lambda\big\vert_{max}^2$, or equivalently for any $j$ we have the point-wise bound
$\Big\Vert Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T \Big\Vert_F^2  \geq \Big( \text{trace}\big(Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\big) \Big)^2$

then summing over the bound and making use of real non-negativity gives the result

*main argument*
$\big \Vert Z \big \Vert_F^2  $
$=\big \Vert Z H\big \Vert_F^2  $
$=\text{trace}\Big(H^T Z Z H\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(Z Z HH^T\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(Z Z \big(\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T \big)\Big)$
$=\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\Big(Z Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T \Big)$
$=\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\Big(Z Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T \Big)$
$=\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\Big(\mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T Z Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T \Big)$
$=\sum_{j=1}^m \Big\Vert Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T \Big\Vert_F^2 $
$\geq \sum_{j=1}^m \Big( \text{trace}\big(Z  \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\big) \Big)^2$
$\geq  \sum_{j=1}^k\Big(\text{trace}\big( Z\mathbf h_t \mathbf h_t^T\big)\Big)^2$

**second proof**
*this is conceptually very close to viewing the problem as a generalization of Bessel's Inequality-- but needs majorization to make the approach stick*

In general we have 
$Z = Q\Lambda Q^T$.  While $Q$ is orthogonal, it may not be equal to $H$.
with eigenvalues in the usual ordering of $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq ... \geq \lambda_m$

*main argument*
$\big \Vert Z  \big \Vert_F^2  $
$=\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j^2 $
$=\sum_{j=1}^m  \Big(\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf q_j \mathbf q_j^T\big) \Big)^2$
$\geq \sum_{j=1}^m  \Big(\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\big) \Big)^2$
$\geq \sum_{j=1}^k\Big(\text{trace}\big( Z\mathbf h_t \mathbf h_t^T\big)\Big)^2$

note: If $H = Q$ then the first inequality becomes equality and the above *is* Bessel's Inequality.  For the most part the first inequality is not met with equality and the relation is justified by Schur Convexity because

$f: x \mapsto x^2$ is (strictly) convex for any $x \in \mathbb R$
and
$\begin{bmatrix}
\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf q_1 \mathbf q_1^T\big)\\ 
\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf q_2 \mathbf q_2^T\big)\\ 
\vdots  \\
\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf q_m \mathbf q_m^T\big)
\end{bmatrix} \succeq \begin{bmatrix}
\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf h_1 \mathbf h_1^T\big)\\ 
\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf h_2 \mathbf h_2^T\big)\\ 
\vdots  \\
\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf h_m \mathbf h_m^T\big)\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

where $\succeq$ denotes majorization.

This is a standard result, but *for an easy proof that majorization holds*
$\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf q_j \mathbf q_j^T\big) $
$=  \text{trace} \big( Z QQ^T\big) $
$=  \text{trace} \big( ZHH^T \big)  $
$= \sum_{j=1}^m\text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\big) $

and for $r\in\{1,2,...,m-1\}$  selecting positive  $\delta$ large enough such that $(\delta I  + Z )$ is positive definite, we have

$ \delta \cdot r + \sum_{j=1}^r \text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf q_j \mathbf q_j^T\big)$
$= \text{trace} \big( (\delta I + Z)\sum_{j=1}^r \mathbf q_j \mathbf q_j^T\big)$
$\geq  \text{trace} \big( (\delta I+Z)\sum_{j=1}^r \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\big)$
$= \delta \cdot r +\sum_{j=1}^r \text{trace} \big( Z \mathbf h_j \mathbf h_j^T\big)$
by the von-Neuman trace inequality